# Why video full path is not working in netBeans IDE?

Tags: javascript, java, html, video

When I use the following code I can't play the video

`<video autoplay controls loop id="vid1" width="100%" height="100%"> <source src="file:///C:/Users/DMS/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VideoView/web/video/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">`

But works when `src="video/example.mp4"`

**And the full path works when i run the html code(not inside any IDE) from folder directly(will show how it works)**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYH8b.png)

When I open *play.html* using firefox as browser then the video plays.**But, When i run the *play.html* inside netBeans IDE video didn't play**. That is, inside netbeans fullpath doesn't works.
`src="file:///C:/Users/DMS/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VideoView/web/video/example.mp4"`  .

Only the source `src="video/example.mp4"` will play the video.
What is the solution?

full code is below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: #666666; /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #666666;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border:none;
  width: 50%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #ff3399;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Flv Video</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Play</button>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    
            <video autoplay controls loop id="vid1" width="100%" height="100%"> <source src="file:///C:/Users/DMS/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VideoView/web/video/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <object data="js/video-js.swf" width="720" height="480"> 
        </object> 
    </video> 
  </div>

</div>

    <script>


            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
            btn.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "block";
            }

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
   var x=document.getElementById("vid1");
   ///alert(x);
            span.onclick = function() {
              modal.style.display = "none";
     x.pause();
     
            }

            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function(event) {
              if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
    x.pause();
              }
            }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the full path doesnt work in Netbeans, is because the html wants to know where the video is inside the project. You have to make the video apart of the project folder.

Also sometimes you can drag the video file into the html code and it will drop a src line with whatever filepath the video has. This will allow you to have a correct filepath and ensure that there are no typos in your file path. It looks like you have too many /// after file, you may only need to start the path begining with "C:" try that!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing NetBeans' default browser.

Tools > Options and select Firefox as your web browser (or any other browser.)